# How do I position the "subhead" and "description" text within the brackets?

Tags: html, css

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/minacosentino/full/NaNmjj)

I'm assuming that it has to do with my positioning (I'm still struggling a bit to understand which is best for specific elements). I also would like the brackets to stay positioned within the column confines in case a user has a narrower window opened.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
  <div class="space margin-10">
    <div class="brackets">
      <h1 class="bracket-l">{</h1>
      <h1 class="bracket-r">}</h1>
      <h2 class="subhead align-center text-up size-1" id="title">HCM</h2>
      <p class="description align-center size-1">Uniting Organizations with HR Solutions that Help Drive Revenue | ADP.com</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.space {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.bracket-l {
  font-family: 'proxima-nova', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
}

.bracket-r {
  font-family: 'proxima-nova', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: what is the issue ? what not just get the whole code from the site you gave, it's working fine, right ?

Comment: No, i'd like the text positioned in-between and within the larger brackets, not positioned below them.

Comment: ok got it, you can check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try this code, using before/after element:

```css
.content {
margin:0 auto;
padding:50px;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
}

.content:before {
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
content:"{";
font-family: 'proxima-nova', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15rem;
  font-weight: 300;

}
.content:after {
position:absolute;
right:0;
top:0;
content:"}";
font-family: 'proxima-nova', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15rem;
  font-weight: 300;

}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<h1>Some text</h1>
<h3>More text More text More text More text</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ur7pyxof/2/

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
  <div class="space margin-10">
    <div class="brackets">
      <h1>
      <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="bracket-l">{</td>
        <td> <h2 class="subhead align-center text-up size-1" id="title">HCM</h2>
      <p class="description align-center size-1">Uniting Organizations with HR Solutions that Help Drive Revenue | ADP.com</p></td>
        <td class="bracket-l">}</td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: why a **table** inside a **h1** ?